# Firefox has lost its titlebar

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, kde, plasma, plasma-5

My Firefox windows (started from a Plasma launcher or by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> in Firefox) appear without a title bar. Other applications are fine. Using Windows action (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd>) on a Firefox window:

- `More actions>No Border` is checked. I can un-check this but it only applies to the current window
- `More actions>Specific applications settings>Appearance & Fixes` appear like below. Is it the right way to fix this? Or is there another setting upstream (which would explain what the setting is grayed out?)?

[image]

And above all, what could have caused the change?

Using Kubuntu 16.04

Comment: Which firefox version are you using?

Comment: FF60.... but I got my answer.

Comment: Yeah, Firefox 60 introduced this optional CSD feature.

Comment: Aw, yes, I see that /usr/lib/firefox/firefox was updated on May 10th on my system. That would correspond. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so it's really Firefox fault. New capability in FF60(*). Found the "Customize" entry in the Tools menu (stripes icon) and the "Title bar" choice was unchecked.

At least my gut feeling that it was due to something else was right...

(*) Thanks to @pomsky for pointing this out